# Get unread e-mail header without reading the e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, email, gmail

I use MailSystem.NET library to access Gmail. I need to get the header from all unread e-mails  **without reading them**. The e-mails from which I read the headers should remain unread. Can I do this? If so, does anyone know how I can achieve this?